# CSS - background-image is showing up on my machine, but not on the hosted version of my site... why?

Tags: html, css, background-image, hosting

For my portfolio site, I had a gif for my background image. It was fine for a few weeks, but now it has stopped working. I tried putting in a different GIF. It looks fine on my local machine, but when pushed up to my host, it no longer works. Not sure what the problem is for it to show up on my computer but not when it's hosted.

[When it's working properly on my machine - see the triangles?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XgpD.png)

[When it's not working on the actual website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyLKn.png)

The site is hosted at http://www.KimberlyScarabello.com.

I'm fairly certain I'm updating the files correctly, because other changes are showing up just fine. This is the CSS that I'm using. I have already tried saving the gifs to my local machine and putting the file path in the url, but that didn't work (though it also works on my machine).

```
#wrapper > .bg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #212931;
        background-image: url('https://media.giphy.com/media/xTg8BbPcaAP43oVyeY/giphy.gif'), linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
        background-size: cover,                             auto,                                                       100% auto;
        background-position: center,                                center,                                                     top center;
        background-repeat: repeat,                              no-repeat,                                                  no-repeat;
        background-attachment: scroll,                              scroll,                                                     scroll;
        z-index: -1;
        filter: brightness(10%)
    }
```

Comment: I see the triangles just fine. Maybe clear your cache

Comment: Holy titballs.. It takes 1 whole minute to load the site. on a ADSL 10/10
https://gyazo.com/2a68cd5d53000323d7d68a8c570d7dad. However, with some optimalization, that site looks awesome! But yeah, its the cache.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me.

This will most likely be caused by your cache. Whenever you have issues like this, just hard reload your site using ctr+f5 (cmd+shift+r for mac I think?). Let me know if that doesn't work for you.